# SQL - How to get the latest date that had any record prior to a specific date?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table t1 as below:

```
 -----------------------------
 |    date   |  id   | value |
 -----------------------------
 | 2/28/2019 |  1    | 55  |
 | 2/28/2019 |  2    | 44  |
 | 2/28/2019 |  3    | 33  |
 | 2/26/2019 |  1    | 22  |
 | 2/26/2019 |  2    | 12  |
 | 2/26/2019 |  3    | 11  |
 -----------------------------
```

I want to take abc3 from t1 and then find abc3 value for date - 1 day in the same table t1 and display both records.

I created a query as:

```
select 
    a.date, a.id, (a.value - b.value) as 'difference-from-previous-day'
FROM 
    t1 a
INNER JOIN
    t1 b
ON 
    a.ID = b.ID
WHERE 
    b.DATE in (dateadd(day, -1, a.DATE));
```

And that works fine when dates are all there.

But there are gaps in dates (e.g. when we look at data for Monday and there is a 'weekend' before Monday - there is no data in table `t1` for last day `-1` so this query shows NULL for Monday)...

How to write a query to pickup last date prior to current date (and NOT `-1` date) for which data exists?

Expecting result:

```
2/28/2019 | 1 | 33     (which is "55 - 22")
2/28/2019 | 2 | 32     (which is "44 - 12")
2/28/2019 | 3 | 22     (which is "33 - 11")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to find the latest date for the latest ID prior to today? Also, are you using SQL Server or MySQL or another database?

Comment: Trying to find latest date for any ID and it's corresponding date. So e.g. Monday has ID=5, looking for latest day before Monday (it would be Friday) and ID of that latest day (ID of Friday). That would be same logic for all records.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using and the version of it? Answers may be product specific in some cases. I bet it's MySQL but can't say for sure, and which version.

Comment: You have an ID column in your table. Is that day of the week (Monday, Tuesday...)?

Comment: MySql and ID column is not corresponding to a day..

Comment: which mysql version you are using?

Comment: MySQL? And you're saying that your query with DATEADD is working?

Comment: Your query does a self join so the results should be in 1 row. How do you get 2 rows?

Comment: *I want to take abc3 from t1 and then find abc3 value for date - 1 day* right, but `abc3` is not the id of the row, for `id = 1` there are in the column `value` these values: `abc1` and `abc4`. Explain which latest date you want: for `id` or for `value`. Better post expected results.

Comment: @all - Added more details.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where t1.value = 'abc'
order by t1.date desc
limit 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a self join on the table like this:

```
select 
  t.date, 
  t.id,
  t.value - tt.value diff
from t1 t inner join t1 tt
on tt.id = t.id
and tt.date = (select max(date) from t1 where date < t.date)
```

Maybe the `inner join` can be changed to a `left join` to cover the case where there is not a previous row for each `id`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/chdYWHBAQZAYNwNMVYYfDf/1).
Results:

```
| date                | id  | diff |
| ------------------- | --- | ---- |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00 | 1   | 33   |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00 | 2   | 32   |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00 | 3   | 22   |
```

Comment: Thanks.. This looks good and makes sense.. but it seems slow.. For a table of 100K+ records - it takes several minutes.. Is there a way to optimize the query?